# How do you rename a GitLab managed Terraform state file without destroying existing infrastructure?

Tags: terraform, gitlab, gitlab-ci, cicd, gitops

I have some Terraform being managed and its IaC deployed via a CI/CD pipeline in GitLab. I currently store the Terraform state in GitLab as well as all other related environments.

However, I have recently run into an issue that is requiring me to change the name of my GitLab managed Terraform state file. How can I modify the name of my state file without having to destroy and/or redeploy infrastructure already managed by the old state file?

I haven't managed to find any resources online indicating how to do so without letting infrastructure go down (which is what I'm trying to avoid).

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on the change that requires changing the state file name? Also, are you using remote or local backend?

Comment: Hi @MarkoE, the backend is remote and managed by GitLab. I can't elaborate on the change that requires changing the state file name (proprietary information).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can migrate the state, but as you'll be doing so within the same project, it'll just be the same as if you have renamed it.

The steps for this process look as follows:

1. First initialise locally the Terraform state with your current state

```
export GITLAB_ACCESS_TOKEN=$YOUR_GITLAB_ACCESS_TOKEN
export TF_ADDRESS="https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/$YOUR_PROJECT_ID/terraform/state/$CURRENT_STATE_NAME"
terraform init \
    -backend-config="address=${TF_ADDRESS}" \
    -backend-config="lock_address=${TF_ADDRESS}/lock" \
    -backend-config="unlock_address=${TF_ADDRESS}/lock" \
    -backend-config="username=$YOUR_USERNAME" \
    -backend-config="password=$GITLAB_ACCESS_TOKEN" \
    -backend-config="lock_method=POST" \
    -backend-config="unlock_method=DELETE" \
    -backend-config="retry_wait_min=5"
```

2. Run `terraform init` with the `-migrate-state` with the new name of the state so it will be copied. You'll have to respond with `yes` on the terminal for the process to kick in.

```
export TF_ADDRESS="https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/$YOUR_PROJECT_ID/terraform/state/$NEW_STATE_NAME"
terraform init \
  -migrate-state \
  -backend-config=address=${TF_ADDRESS} \
  -backend-config=lock_address=${TF_ADDRESS}/lock \
  -backend-config=unlock_address=${TF_ADDRESS}/lock \
  -backend-config=username=$YOUR_GITLAB_USERNAME \
  -backend-config=password=${GITLAB_ACCESS_TOKEN} \
  -backend-config=lock_method=POST \
  -backend-config=unlock_method=DELETE \
  -backend-config=retry_wait_min=5
```

Having run the above two commands, you can navigate to `Operate > Terraform States` and double-check that a new state has been created according to the value of `$NEW_STATE_NAME`. And from now on if your CI variable `$TF_STATE_NAME` makes use of this new value the config will be able to use it.

Hope it helps!